# Hover background color not filling CSS grid correctly

Tags: html, css, hover, css-grid

```css
.body{

}

.grid-container{
 display: grid;
 width: 1024px;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
 background-color: black;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px auto;
}

#home, #about, #bookings, #contact {
 padding: 5px 5px;
 margin: 5px 5px;
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid white;
 font-weight: bold;
} 

#home, #about, #bookings, #contact, a:hover {
 background-color: red;
}

#home, #about, #bookings, #contact, a:link {
 color: white;

}

#home, #about, #bookings, #contact, a:visited {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}



#home{
 grid-column-start: 1;
 grid-column-end: 2;
}


#about{
 grid-column-start: 2;
 grid-column-end: 3;
}

#bookings{
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 4;
}

#contact{
 grid-column-start: 4;
 grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>

<html>

<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="test2Style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class = "grid-container">
   <div id = "home"><a href = "home.html">Home</a></div>
   <div id = "about"><a href = "home.html">About us</a></div>
   <div id = "bookings"><a href = "home.html">Bookings</a></div>
   <div id = "contact"><a href = "home.html">Contact Us</a></div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I am trying to build a simple menu in grid and then expand it later once I have got the first part working.

I am trying to set up the menu so that you hover over the hyperlink the background changes colour to red however it currently only changes a bit of background behind the text.

I have tried messing about with the overflow property and have recognised that I probably need look towards changing something other than the background color of the id #home using hover.

I would expect the entire background for each menu item to change colour rather than just the small bit of text but I just cant figure it out and I am coming up with nothing trying to search for the issue.

If you can't tell I am new to CSS so feel free to criticise my html/CSS and point out anything else that is wrong or not best practice.

Thanks for looking,

Comment: instead of having `id`s for all the divs, why not use something like `.grid-container > div`? also `#home, #about, #bookings, #contact, a:hover` does not mean hover for all of them, the hover  style is applied to only `a`; correct would be `#home:hover, #about:hover, #bookings:hover, #contact:hover, a:hover` (or you can just use `.grid-container > div:hover` which may be all what you need here)

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks for that, I will look into the .grid-container > div stuff. Appreciate you clearing up the :hover issue too, I just assumed it would work for them all :)

Comment: cool, revise your code and if it still don't work out, update it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you applied a background color to the link instead of the surrounding div which is the actual grid cell. One solution would be to instead apply that red background to the divs on hover, like in this minimal example:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 100px;
}

div:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

But a much better idea would be to remove the div from around the links, which is entirely useless. Make the whole box be the link instead; it also makes it easier to click the link.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 100px;
}

a:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

While we're at it, I'll simplify the CSS; you really don't need all those ids, and you especially don't need to position the cells manually. Try to keep your CSS selectors as simple as possible. If they get a little complex, it's a sign you should add more classes to your code.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container a {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}

.grid-container a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="home.html">About us</a>
  <a href="home.html">Bookings</a>
  <a href="home.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

With all of that said, you should get familiar with how the browser's [inspection window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector), which lets you debug your code and see what CSS is applied to what elements. All modern browsers have one.

Comment: Wicked, really appreciate that reply Jacque :).

Comment: If you want this question to be marked as resolved, just mark this as the "accepted answer" using the green checkmark.